# 2D array populating not working

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm trying to populate a 2D array with char's from a string I've read in. I'm having a problem with actually populating this 2D array. It keeps printing a 2D array bigger than what I've given it, and the number always seems to be 6 rather than the letters from the string.

I store the string in an ArrayList called tempArray.

Input strings:
    `WUBDLAIUWBD`
    `LUBELUFBSLI`
    `SLUEFLISUEB`

I instantiate a 2D array with columnlength = 11, and rowcount 3
`epidemicArray = new int[rowCount][columnCount];`

Array before I try to populate it:

```
00000000000
00000000000
00000000000
```

My code:

```
public static void updateArray(){
    //extract string from temp
    for (int i = 0; i < tempArray.size(); i++){
        String temp = tempArray.get(i);
        char[] charz = temp.toCharArray();
        for (int j = 0; j < charz.length; j++){
            for (int k = 0; k < rowCount; k++){
                for (int l = 0; l < columnCount; l++){
                    epidemicArray[k][l] = charz[j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output: Which I didn't expect

```
6666666666666666666666
6666666666666666666666
6666666666666666666666
```

Expected output: (2D array)

```
WUBDLAIUWBD
LUBELUFBSLI
SLUEFLISUEB
```

Thanks, this is really bugging me.

Comment: What do you expect for your output?

Comment: Four for loops give me nightmares. If you're just trying to populate a 2D array you really should only need two loops unless your doing something weird.

Comment: Show the arrays being defined and initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
public static void updateArray(){
    //extract string from temp
    for (int i = 0; i < tempArray.size(); i++){
        String temp = tempArray.get(i);
        char[] charz = temp.toCharArray();
        for (int j = 0; j < charz.length; j++){ 
                epidemicArray[i][j] = charz[j];
        }
    }
}
```

This edit should work since the number of columns is the length of one of the string (same length for the 3 of them).

Here is my output

[image: ArrayList to array]

[EDIT]. @magna_nz, I used the following methods to print the array

```
public static void printRow(int rowNumber) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        System.out.print( epidemicArray[rowNumber][i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    updateArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printRow(i);
    }
}
```

This will print the numbers, but if you want to print characters you can change the above printRow method to something like:

```
public static void printRow(int rowNumber) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        System.out.print( (char)epidemicArray[rowNumber][i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

And this will give you the following result:

[image: in chars]

Comment: 6868686868686868686868
    7373737373737373737373
    6666666666666666666666

Is the output. Not working.

Comment: `8785666876657385876668`
`7685666976857066837673`
`8376856970767383856966`

Is what i get. But why isn't it showing numbers instead of chracters?? Also, why is the length greater than 11 (when that was the maximum size I allowed to array to be)?

Comment: @magna_nz, The lenght is not greater than 11, it is exactly 11. When you print it, add a space separator between each print, like I did in the picture that I have added to my reply

Comment: @magna_nz since you use an int array to store the character, it gives you the numeric value corresponding to each character, For example, the corresponding value for capitalized A is 65 the corresponding value for B is 66 and for Z it  would be 65 + 25 =90

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting your entire `epidemicArray` with the last value that `charz[j]` gets.  Which is apparently 66.  Actually you're overwriting that entire array with every value from `charz` and the last one won.

Comment: (Actually it's 66, the ASCII value for 'B', the last char of the last string of OP's input.)

Comment: Ah yes.  That does explain why the output looks twice as big as the arrays initial value. :)